# No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to iterate an array, however the code fails with the following error message:

> No visible @interface for `NSObject` declares the selector `objectAtIndex:`

Here is how my code looks like:

```objc
_elements = [NSMutableArray array];
[_elements addObject:_arrins1 ];
[_elements addObject:_arrins2 ];
[_elements addObject:_arrins3 ];

_arrins1 = [NSMutableArray array];
[_arrins1 addObject:ins1.title = @"test1"];
[_arrins1 addObject:ins1.size = @90];
[_arrins1 addObject:ins1.text = @"example"];
[_arrins1 addObject:ins1.ids = @0];

_arrins2 = [NSMutableArray array];
[_arrins2 addObject:ins2.title = @"test2"];
[_arrins2 addObject:ins2.size = @40];
[_arrins2 addObject:ins2.text = @"example"];
[_arrins2 addObject:ins2.ids = @1];


_arrins3 = [NSMutableArray array];
[_arrins3 addObject:ins3.title = @"test3"];
[_arrins3 addObject:ins3.size = @20];
[_arrins3 addObject:ins3.text = @"example"];
[_arrins3 addObject:ins3.ids = @2];
```

```objc
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat height = 0;
    for (NSObject *j in _elements) {
        // Error: No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'
        height = [j objectAtIndex:1];
    }

    return height;
}
```

I also tried to change the type of elements in the loop, but it didn't help:

```objc
for (id j in _elements) {
    // Error: Assigning to 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'id'
    height = [j objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Your code is strange, I'd expect `NSNumber * heightNumber = [_elements objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; return [heightNumber floatValue];`.

Comment: Hi @Larme, hope u doing well :), I think I didnt properly explain what I want to do. I'll edit the question. _elements is an array that contains 3 arrays and each of them has objects, thats why I do it in a for-in loop

Comment: `_elements` should be an array of object `ins`. It's better design. Else `for (NSArray * aSubArray in _elements) { NSNumber * heightNumber = [_elements objectAtIndex:[1]]; height += [heightNumber floatValue]; }`

Comment: Ty so much for your responses it help me ! @Larme @vadian                                                   I did this:  `for ( NSArray *j in _elements) {
         heightNumber = [ j objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"test");
        
    }`                                                                                                                                          Have a nice day!

Comment: I'll modify _elements, u are right :) Ty so much for your help, what do u think about the code I did on the response, it's a good way to do it ?

Comment: The loop makes no sense, it returns always the value of the last item in the array. `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called multiple times, once for each row. You have to return the value for the row at the given index path.

Comment: Hi @vadian u are right, I was wondering how to return the three values hehe, ty for your reply :)